# Conditional matching of a string at the end of the line using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to create a Regex pattern in C# where it is able to take in a string, capture 3 groups, where the final group only captures if the string ends with 'NoClause'. I've provided below a sample input and what I'd like the 3 capture groups to contain.

Sample Input:

`Header:Select * From TableName WHERE ColumnName = '53 : ABC' ORDER BY NoClause : NoClause`

Desired Output:

```
Group1: 'Header'
Group2: 'Select * From TableName WHERE ColumnName = '53 : ABC''
Group3: 'NoClause'
```

The pattern I have so far is:

`(\w+):{1}(.+)\s*:\s*(NoClause)`

Now for when the string is formatted as the sample input, **this does work** but the issue I have is when the input string **doesn't contain ': NoClause'**, in these scenarios that capture group should contain nothing. I've provided examples below of when this doesn't work but needs to.

```
Header:select * from TableName where ColumnName = '1 ABC'
Header:select * from TableName where ColumnName = '1: ABC'
Header:select * from TableName where ColumnName = '1: ABC' OR ColumnName = '2: DFG' OR ColumnName = '3: HIJ'
```

When using the above pattern, nothing captures at all. I've attempted to use the '?' as a conditional but am unable to have it match all cases.

I've been fiddling with this all at https://regex101.com/r/wG3aM3/261.

**Things to consider**

1. When using this pattern, only one string of input will be processed
   at a time, not for example, four separate inputs processed at once
2. I have the C# code all ready to go, just need the Regex pattern to make it
   work
3. The input string will sometimes contain 0 or more semi-colons (:)
   but it is only after the final semi-colon do I want it to capture
   the 'NoClause'
4. This needs to support the edge case, where a ColumnName or value is 'NoClause', very unlikely but needs to support this case regardless.

For interest, the below is my C# code.

```
Match parameters = Regex.Match(inputString, @"(\w+):{1}(.+)\s*:\s*(NoClause)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var group1 = parameters.Groups[1].Value;
var group2 = parameters.Groups[2].Value;
bool group3 = parameters.Groups[3].Success;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with this one:

```
^(\w+):(.+?)(?:\s*:\s*(NoClause|NoWhereClause))?$
```

You need to make the last part optional. Also you need to use lazy matching in the middle to avoid capturing the content of the last group into the middle one.

Comment: Thanks! Appears to be working! I slightly edited it to not capture an unnecessary group. `^(\w+):(.+?)(?:\s*:\s*(NoClause))?$` (verify at https://regex101.com/r/wG3aM3/262)

Comment: Strange, when I used this in my C# project, the unit tests failed. Tried another online tool to help debug and the results aren't the same as before as it doesn't capture the 3rd group at all, ideas? [RegexStorm Test Results](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5cw%2b%29%3a%28.%2b%3f%29%28%3f%3a%5cs*%3a%5cs*%28NoClause%29%29%3f%24&i=Header%3aselect+*+from+%23%23HeaderTest+where+MultiLineText+%3d+%271%3a+ABC%27+OR+MultiLineText+%3d+%272%3a+DFG%27+OR+MultiLineText+%3d+%273%3a+HIJ%27+%3a++++++++++++++++++++NoWhereClause&o=i)

Comment: Your failed unit test contains `NoWhereClause` instead of `NoClause`, which you did not mention in the original post. I tweaked the regex.

Comment: Oh woops! That is embarrassing! My bad, thanks for the pickup! Didn't mean for it to contain NoWhereClause, forgot to tweak my unit tests.